# RandomForestClassifier visualization - overlapping colours

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am visualizing the result of a RandomForestClassifier by using the following code:

```
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=300, centers=4,
                         random_state=0, cluster_std=1.0)

def visualize_classifier(model, X, y, ax=None, cmap='rainbow'):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    # Plot the training points
    ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=30, cmap=cmap,
               clim=(y.min(), y.max()), zorder=3)
    ax.axis('tight')
    ax.axis('off')
    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    # fit the estimator
    model.fit(X, y)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(*xlim, num=200),
                         np.linspace(*ylim, num=200))
    Z = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]).reshape(xx.shape)
    # Create a color plot with the results
    n_classes = len(np.unique(y))
    contours = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, alpha=0.3,
                           levels=np.arange(n_classes + 1) - 0.5,
                           cmap=cmap, clim=(y.min(), y.max()),
                           zorder=1)
    ax.set(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
bag = BaggingClassifier(tree, n_estimators=100, max_samples=0.8, random_state=1)
bag.fit(X, y)
visualize_classifier(bag, X, y)
```

[image]

I have noticed, that some borders of the areas comprise different colours.
[image]

I am pretty sure that this behaviour has nothing to do with the data I use but has some mathematical/ graphical background....So whats the reason for this misrepresentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to predict points on the border, it gave me reasonable predictions (that is, predictions that are associated with one of the two big regions near the border) and not predictions that are associated with the border colour.

Hence I guess that the reason for the different border colour is that the border is not represented in the meshgrid (that is, no point from the meshgrid falls right on the border), while the two sides of the border are represented in the meshgrid, so the visualization tool has no knowledge about what should be the correct colour.

If you switch

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(*xlim, num=200),
                         np.linspace(*ylim, num=200))
```

into

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(*xlim, num=2000),
                         np.linspace(*ylim, num=2000))
```

(that is, increase 200 to 2000. Note that the code is slower as it takes a while to produce the classification in this case), you get more accurate figure and many parts of the overlapping borders disappear.